# Quadratic function in standard form? Two possibles answers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

In the book, Algebra and Trigonometry by James Stewart he teaches how to express f in the standard form, however I have seen another teachers teaching it differently. So I came up with two answers for the same problem:

Answer 1 (James Stewart's book)
$F(x)= 5x^2-30x+49$

$5(x-3)^2+4$

AND...

$5(x-3)^2+94$

Which answer is the correct one?

Edit: The difference between these two answers come by subtracting and adding ($49-5*9$ and $49+5*9$). My main doubt is if I should add or subtract the last numbers. I'm sure the process that led to these numbers are correct, I just don't know if I have to add or subtract them. Thanks!

Comment: See what happens when $x=0$ for example. You didn't say *how* you came up with the two answers.

Comment: Oh sorry. For the first question it was: 5(x-3)^2 + 49 -5*9. For the second answer it was by adding +49+45, what gives 5(x-3)^2+94. My main doubt is if I should subtract or add these last numbers. Thanks.

Comment: $x^2-6x=(x^2-6x+\color{red}{9}) \color{red}{- 9}=(x-3)^2\color{red}{-9}\,$, so you must subtract whatever was added to complete the square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By completing the square we get:

$f(x)=5 \cdot (x^2-6x+9) + 49 - 45$ which is

$f(x)=5 \cdot (x-3)^{2} + 4$.

Hence, by adding $5 \cdot 9$ we need to subtract $5 \cdot 9$. Each step you want to make sure that your equation hasn't changed.

Comment: Many thanks you helped me a lot!

Comment: @Elton You are welcome.